# Многопоточность в Java реализация

Tags: java, многопоточность

Объясните пожалуйста как реализовать многопоточное приложение!
Имеется класс типа CRUD со статическими методами и коллекцией с элементами:

```
public class Crud {

    protected static List<User> users = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    static {
        initialize();
    }

    protected static void initialize() {
        users.add(new User("Name1", "Surname1", 27));
        users.add(new User("Name2", "Surname2", 27));
        users.add(new User("Name3", "Surname3", 26));
        users.add(new User("Name4",  "Surname4", 26));
        users.add(new User("Name5", "Surname5", 28));
    }

    public static void insert(User user) {
        users.add(user);
    }

    public static void delete(int index) {
        users.remove(index);
    }

    public static void update(int index, User user) {
        users.set(index, user);
    }

    public static void show() {
        Iterator it = users.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            User user = (User)it.next();
            System.out.println(user.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void show(int index) {
        User user = users.get(index);
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }  
}
```

Нужно реализовать в методе `main(String[] args)` многопоточность для одновременного извлечения и изменения данных в коллекции.
Это чисто тестовое приложение ни какая не реализация, чисто в учебных целях.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: После того, как реализуете многопоточность, столкнетесь с тем, что ваш класс непотокобезопасен. В частности, перебор synchronized list не является потокобезопасной операцией и требует синхронизации (между вызовами `next()` запросто может вклиниться другой поток, добавив или удалив элемент). Поэтому от обертки можно будет отказаться и синхронизировать любой доступ к коллекции (за исключением конструктора) руками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не буду расписывать классический подход с ручным созданием отдельных тредов (хотя с ним стоит ознакомиться, чтобы знать, как работает внутри), самым общеупотребимым подходом для параллелизации задач является создание и использование `ThreadPoolExecutor` (как реализацию интерфейсов `Executor` и `ExecutorService`):

```
// создаст ThreadPoolExecutor из четырех тредов
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
executor.submit(new Runnable() {
     // этот код будет выполняться в произвольном потоке ThreadPoolExecutor
     crud.show(1);
});
// запрещает добавление новых задач и подготавливает ThreadPoolExecutor к завершению
executor.shutdown();
// ожидает завершение ThreadPoolExecutor'a
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но может распишете классический подход?)))) Понимаю что это время затратно.

Comment: @ElSalvadore только если время будет

Comment: Ок. и еще, точно ли в этом примере будет реализована синхронизация?

Comment: @ElSalvadore нет, ее точно здесь не будет. Я воспринял вопрос как необходимость создать окружение, в котором будет организован многопоточный доступ и только, задача по подготовке к таким условиям лежит на исполняемом коде, т.е. вашем Crud. В данный момент, если вы накидаете много изменяющих состояние тасков в TPE, вы скорее всего будете наблюдать соответствующие феномены вроде потерянных записей.